# Call animation on objects inside Style in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I've got own style for PanningTitleLayer in Panorama Page and I am trying to setup animation to object inside that style. But from code-behind I can't see objects like ClockAnimation or TextCoffeeTimerFirst.

So I can't call ClockAnimation.Begin() from code - behind. I can just call CoffeePanningTitleLayerStyle but I also don't have access to TextCoffeeTimerFirst etc.

Question is - what should I do to call animation for object from my style?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CoffeePanningTitleLayerStyle" TargetType="Primitives:PanningTitleLayer">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Primitives:PanningTitleLayer">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="PanningStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Name="ClockAnimation">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextCoffeeTimerFirst">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="4"/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="8"/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="2"/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="9"/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="5"/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="3"/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="7"/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="6"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextCoffeeTimerFirst">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Bounces="9" Bounciness="-2"/>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="15">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Bounces="9" Bounciness="-2"/>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="0">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Bounces="9" Bounciness="-2"/>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </StackPanel.Resources>
                            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="PanningTransform"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="LocalTransform"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                            <Border x:Name="LeftWraparound"/>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Margin="0,12"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextCoffeeTimerFirst" Text="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="80" Foreground="#FFB93325" FontFamily="/TAB.WindowsPhone;component/Fonts/BNR.ttf#Bebas Neue Bold" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="60" TextAlignment="Right">
                                                            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                                                <CompositeTransform/>
                                                            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                                        </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Border x:Name="RightWraparound"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: VisualTreeHelper might be a solution but in reality: Only put storyboards into a style, if they are used with a visual state.

Comment: Other Idea: You could use Triggers (Behaviors) that trigger your Animations.

Comment: @KaiBrummund hmm so If I would like to use visual state like trigger when my textbox - it's acceptable?

Comment: You Need to check which states are available in the original control template. You can only use those by default. I don't think that style triggers are supported in winRT.